# React, losing saved data in localStorage with useEffect after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

This is probably a noob question, but I'm facing some troubles with the `useEffect()` hook. I have a Taking Notes App, and I want to make the data persist. I'm using 2 `useEffect`s: one for when the page is refreshed/loaded by the first time, and other one for when I add a new note to my app.

I putted some logs to check what's happening:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([
  {
  noteId: nanoid(),
  text: 'This is my 1st note!',
  date: '30/07/2022'
  },
  {
    noteId: nanoid(),
    text: 'This is my 2nd note!',
    date: '30/07/2022'
  }
])

// 1st time the app runs
useEffect(() => {
  const savedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-notes'))
  console.log('refresh page call:',savedNotes)

  if(savedNotes) {
    setNotes(savedNotes)
  }
}, [])

//every time a new note is added
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('react-notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
  console.log('new note call:', notes)
}, [notes])
```

The behaviour is a bit strange, because when the page is refreshed the new data is appearing inside the log, but then it disappears, maintaining only the hardcoded data:

[image]

It also makes more calls than I was expecting to. Any thoughts about what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

The problem is caused by the below `useEffect` and how you are initially setting the state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('react-notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
  console.log('new note call:', notes)
}, [notes])
```

The above `useEffect` runs every time `notes` changes, but also on mount. And on mount the state is equal to that initial array given to `useState`. So the `localStorage` is set to that array.

## Solution

A solution is to change how you are setting the state as below, so you pick what's in the `localStroge` if there is something, and otherwise use that initial array you have:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState(
  !localStorage.getItem("react-notes")
    ? [
        {
          noteId: nanoid(),
          text: "This is my 1st note!",
          date: "30/07/2022",
        },
        {
          noteId: nanoid(),
          text: "This is my 2nd note!",
          date: "30/07/2022",
        },
      ]
    : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("react-notes"))
);
```