# Not able to store data in local storage and use it on page refresh in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, local-storage

I’m using Firebase version `8.10.0` as the DB in my application, and I succeeded to show the data in my page. So generally Firebase consumes `useEffect` to show the data.

Also I succeeded to drag and drop the positions of table that contains Firebase data. But my pain is to store the drag and drop positions in a state and that state should be stored in `localStorage`.

My destination is to create a separate state that to be stored dragged items in `localStorage`. I tried this code, but I didn't get any result:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./BootTable.css";
import "./Appa.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import firebaseDB from "./firebased";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

function App() {
  const dragItem = useRef();
  const dragOverItem = useRef();
  const [getData, setGetData] = useState({});

  //To Show the data
  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDB.child("register").on("value", (details) => {
      console.log(details.val());
      setGetData(details.val());
    });
  }, []);

  // To Store the dragged data into localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("MY_DRAGGED_DATA");
    if (data !== null) setGetData(JSON.parse(data));
  }, []);

 // To set the item to localstorage

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("show data", getData);

    window.localStorage.setItem("MY_DRAGGED_DATA", JSON.stringify(getData));
  }, [getData]);

  const deleteHandler = (key) => {
    firebaseDB.child(`register/${key}`).remove(() =>
      toast.error("Deleted!", {
        position: "top-right",
      })
    );
  };

  const dragStart = (e, position) => {
    dragItem.current = position;
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  };

  const dragEnter = (e, position) => {
    dragOverItem.current = position;
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  };
  const drop = (e) => {
    const copyListItems = [...Object.values(getData)];
    const dragItemContent = copyListItems[dragItem.current];
    copyListItems.splice(dragItem.current, 1);
    copyListItems.splice(dragOverItem.current, 0, dragItemContent);
    dragItem.current = null;
    dragOverItem.current = null;
    setGetData(copyListItems);
  };

  return (
    <div className="full_Container">
      <center>
        <h6 className="h6_heading">Winners</h6>
      </center>

      <table className="table " id="data-table">
        <thead className="table-hero">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">S.no</th>
            <th className="put_pointer" scope="col">
              Name ▲▼
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              Company Name
            </th>
            <th className="put_pointer" scope="col">
              LTP
            </th>
            <th className="put_pointer" scope="col">
              %
            </th>
            <th className="put_pointer" scope="col">
              52 W.H
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              52 W.L
            </th>
            <th scope="col">M.B</th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              Mkt.Cap
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              Volume
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              Zauba
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              M.C
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              N
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              C.I
            </th>
            <th className="" scope="col">
              Del
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {getData &&
            Object.keys(getData).map((key, index) => (
              <tr
                style={{ cursor: "move" }}
                onDragStart={(e) => dragStart(e, index)}
                onDragEnter={(e) => dragEnter(e, index)}
                onDragEnd={drop}
                key={index}
                draggablekey={index}
                draggable
              >
                <td>{index + 1}</td>

                <td>
                  <a
                    target="_blank"
                    style={{ color: "#212529" }}
                    href={getData[key].url}
                  >
                    {getData[key].name}
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  {" "}
                  <a
                    target="_blank"
                    style={{ color: "#212529" }}
                    href={getData[key].tradingview}
                  >
                    {getData[key].companyname}
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>{getData[key].ltp}</td>
                <td>{getData[key].percent}</td>
                <td className="wk_low">{getData[key].weekhigh}</td>
                <td className="wk_low">{getData[key].weeklow}</td>
                <td className="wk_high">
                  {(getData[key].weekhigh / getData[key].weeklow).toFixed(2)}
                </td>
                <td>{getData[key].mcap}</td>
                <td>{getData[key].volume}</td>

                <td>
                  <a target="_blank" href={getData[key].zauba}>
                    <button
                      style={{
                        color: "#D39B16",
                        padding: "3px",
                        fontWeight: 1000,
                      }}
                      className="btn   btn-sm"
                    >
                      Z
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a target="_blank" href={getData[key].mc}>
                    <button
                      style={{
                        color: "#FF60AB",
                        padding: "3px",
                        fontWeight: 1000,
                      }}
                      className="btn  btn-sm"
                    >
                      M
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a target="_blank" href={getData[key].mc}>
                    <button
                      style={{
                        color: "#19be7b",
                        padding: "3px",
                        fontWeight: 1000,
                      }}
                      className="btn  btn-sm"
                    >
                      N
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a target="_blank" href={getData[key].ci}>
                    <button
                      style={{
                        color: "#19be7b",
                        padding: "3px",
                        fontWeight: 1000,
                      }}
                      className="btn  btn-sm"
                    >
                      C.I
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    style={{ color: "#fff", padding: "3px", fontWeight: 1000 }}
                    className="btn  btn-sm btn-danger"
                    onClick={() => deleteHandler(key)}
                  >
                    Del
                  </button>
                </td>
                {/* {`https://roohhi.com/convert?name=${(filteredPerson.company.toLowerCase().replace(".",""))}` } */}
              </tr>

              //     <tr>{index}</tr>
              // <tr><a>{getData[key].url}{getData[key].companyname}</a></tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <ToastContainer theme="colored" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, losing saved data in localStorage with useEffect after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177643/react-losing-saved-data-in-localstorage-with-useeffect-after-page-refresh)

Comment: Inside `drop()` you are calling `setGetData(copyListItems)`, is't that you want to have that `copyListItems` from the localStorage on refresh if there is data there? And only fetch from Firebase if there isn't' any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have what you want you should first change how you are setting your initial state so that you pick what's in the `localStorage` if there is any and otherwise set it to `null`:

```js
const [getData, setGetData] = useState(
  localStorage.getItem("MY_DRAGGED_DATA")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MY_DRAGGED_DATA"))
    : null
);
```

And make sure you only use the data from Firebase if the initial data is `null` (I used `null` to have a falsy value) and that it's the first render (with `loadRef`), like so:

```js
const loadRef = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
  firebaseDB.child("register").on("value", (details) => {
    if (getData && loadRef.current){
      loadRef.current = false;
      return
    }
    console.log(details.val());
    setGetData(details.val());
  });
}, []); // the linter might ask you to add getData in the dependency array but don't, and you will be fine.
```