# React App doesnt store data to local storage after refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

My react app will save data to local storage but when refreshed the data disappears. What am I doing wrong with local storage?

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
    import NoteList from "./components/noteList";
    import Search from "./components/search";
    import Header from "./components/header";

const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const savedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes-data"));

    if (savedNotes) {
      setNotes(savedNotes);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("notes-data", JSON.stringify(notes));
  }, [notes]);

  const addNote = (text) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
    };
    const newNotes = [...notes, newNote];
    setNotes(newNotes);
  };

  const deleteNote = (id) => {
    const newNotes = notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id);
    setNotes(newNotes);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Search handleSearchNote={setSearchText} />
        <NoteList
          notes={notes.filter((note) =>
            note.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
          )}
          handleAddNote={addNote}
          handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

From everything that I have read I can't see what I'm doing wrong unless its something simple.

[This is pre refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG1ok.png)

[this is post refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0qBb.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, losing saved data in localStorage with useEffect after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177643/react-losing-saved-data-in-localstorage-with-useeffect-after-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second **useEffect** hook since it is executing depending on **notes** array (initially is empty), this causes the localstorage data to be "erased" (in reality it is updated to an empty array after component mounts).

To understand better what I mean add a console log here to see when it is executing and what data is saved.

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('saving data to local storage', notes);

localStorage.setItem("notes-data", JSON.stringify(notes));
}, [notes]);
```

**Update:**

You can handle that by **stoping** the **useEffect** execution on first render (for more information check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render))

Comment: Thank you for the help. Turns out the problem was that Strictmode was causing it to run twice.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of this code snippet
`useEffect(() => { localStorage.setItem("notes-data", JSON.stringify(notes)); }, [notes]);`

Before setting notes-data please check if the localStorage has notes-data already set using `localStorage.getItem("notes-data")` in an if condition.

Answer (score 0):

it's because your react Component is rendering twice and to solve this issue you have to disable the <React.StrictMode> in your index.js file:-
For example, you might find that your  is wrapped by <React.StrictMode> in your index.js:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
     <React.StrictMode>
       <App />
     </React.StrictMode>,
  );
```

If so, you can disable StrictMode by removing the <React.StrictMode> tag:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
  );
```