# LocalStorage is empty in the 1st render NEXT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, e-commerce, react-context

Im creating a shopping cart with NextJS and it works, but when I try to console log the length of my cart, in the first render it appears empty so it gives me a bunch of problems.

```
    const initialState = {};
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    if (cartData) {
      setCart(cartData);
    }
  }, []);  

  useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

  }, [cart]);
```

All cart methods such as DeleteCart, AddToCart, etc work fine.
Any idea?

Comment: In the first render it is obviously empty as you initialized it with `{}` ...

Comment: Yes but how can I initialize it with the saved cart? I dont know how to achieve this in Nextjs as I do in React.

Comment: By default, you can't initialise the `cart` state variable with a value from `localStorage` because it'll cause an error when the page gets pre-rendered on the server by Next.js. You have two options: 1) Set the `cart` variable with the value from `localStorage` inside a `useEffect`; 2) Use `next/dynamic` with `ssr: false` to only load the component where this logic happens on the client-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, losing saved data in localStorage with useEffect after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177643/react-losing-saved-data-in-localstorage-with-useeffect-after-page-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

You are 'almost' looping these two `useEffect`. Try this:

```
  const initialState = {};
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    if (cartData) {
      setCart(cartData);
    }
  }, []);  

  useEffect(() => {
      if(Object.keys(cart).length > 0){
          localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
      {
  }, [cart]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent you from clearing the cart though?

Comment: It is giving 0 length again when refresh. Also I need to redirect to homepage when the cart is empty, so it will always redirect me when refresh because it 0 when it is not.

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom no