# Local Storage gets refreshed when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am building a notes app. I want to save the notes entered by the user in the Local Storage so that I can get it even after I refresh my page. The local storage is working properly but as soon as I refresh the items from the local storage get deleted.

```js
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

// This is the state variable that contains all the notes that are entered by the user. 

useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('react-notes-app-data', JSON.stringify(notes));
}, [notes]);

useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem('react-notes-app-data');
    if (data !== null) setNotes(JSON.parse(data));
}, []);
```

I have used these two `useEffect()` hooks. The first one adds the note entered by the user into the local storage, every time the notes state gets updated. I have given it a key of 'reacet-notes-app-data'.

The second `useEffect()` is supposed to render the notes from the local storage, the first time I render my page. So I check if the data is null or not. If it is not null I update the notes array with the elements already present in the local storage. But it does not show the already present items. Basically when I refresh the local storage gets refreshed too and gets empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, losing saved data in localStorage with useEffect after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177643/react-losing-saved-data-in-localstorage-with-useeffect-after-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

When the page gets refreshed the initial state of notes set as an empty array `[]`

Solution:

```
const savedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-notes-app-data'));
const [notes, setNotes] = useState(savedNotes || []);
```

Hope it works fine. If it still does not work then please share the code where you update the state notes.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the solution. But when I refresh the notes variable is being set as an empty array, understood. But when I refresh also the useEffect is getting called so the notes array is being updated so why is it still staying empty?

Comment: The code of useEffect executes after the component is mounted on the UI. First of all initial value of the state notes is assigned to the state and then the return part of the component is executed and then useEffect is executed. And that's why when component render for the first time it get empty array as the value of notes.

Comment: For more please learn about the component lifecycle https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-understand-a-components-lifecycle-methods-in-reactjs-e1a609840630/#:~:text=We%20are%20born%2C%20grow%2C%20and,to%20as%20a%20component%20lifecycle.