# when i reload the page local storage will be empty so i want to store data after reloading in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
//Fetch the Value from Local Storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    if (retrieveContacts) {
      setContacts(JSON.parse(retrieveContacts));
    }
  }, []);
  //Storage the Value
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);
```

i tried to fetch data from local storage but it's not working

Comment: can you please  share the actual error that you got it would be better and more  precise:

is this what you are trying to do :
The first useEffect hook retrieves the value from local storage using localStorage.getItem and JSON.parse to parse the retrieved value into an array. If there is a value retrieved from local storage, it sets the contacts state variable to the parsed value.

The second useEffect hook stores the value of contacts in local storage using localStorage.setItem and JSON.stringify to convert the contacts array into a string.

Comment: Basically, i want to store data in local storage that is fine but when i reload the page local storage will be empty so i want to store data after reloading. That's my main concern not get any error. thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to say how exactly it isn't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177643/react-losing-saved-data-in-localstorage-with-useeffect-after-page-refresh.

Comment: @yousoumar Yeah my issue is the same but my value is not hard coded.

Comment: Just replace the array by`[]` and you should be good.

Comment: @yousoumar every load empties the array so first, I need to store the data in the array than will go for fetching.

Comment: What is the value you're getting as retrieveContacts ?

Comment: @TayyabHassan It's disrespectful that you completely ignore two people who answered your question

Comment: @TreverThompson I didn't ignore the answer. I didn't see the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `useEffect` hooks is the issue. At the second `useffect` setting the 'contacts' s not happeing since the first one hasn't yet been set. So the value of setting the localstorage goes null. Instead have the value set at the point of useState hooks. Also, when you are using `localStorage`, it's important to handle the initial state as well. Try the code below.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App2 = () => {

const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'key-1'
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) : {name:'james', count:0}
);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  const handleButtonClickEvent = () => {
    setContacts({name:'james', count:contacts.count + 1})
  }

  return (
    <>
        <div>Name: {contacts.name}</div>
        <div>Country: {contacts.count}</div>
        <input type='button' value='button' onClick={(e) => handleButtonClickEvent()}></input>
    </>
    
  )
}

export default App2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your local storage will be empty after every reload because your default 'contacts' value is an empty array. Your second `useEffect` then saves this empty array to local storage when the component mounts, overwriting whatever value was previously saved there.

You can resolve this by getting rid of your first `useEffect`, and loading the default 'contacts' value from local storage:

```
 const retrieveContacts = () => localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY) || []; // Outside of component

 ...

 const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(() => retrieveContacts()); // Inside of component
 useEffect(() => {
   localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
 }, [contacts]);
```