# Custom Next.js hook refreshing local storage memory on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have created a custom Next.js hook called useLocalStorage to persist data in local storage. It's working fine like when trying to update the data then the local storage is being updated, but the local storage memory is getting refreshed on every render. How can I prevent this behavior?

```js
import { SetStateAction, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function useLocalStorage(
  key: string,
  initialState: string
): [state: string, setState: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>] {
  const [state, setState] = useState<string>(initialState || "");

  useEffect(() => {
    let savedValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (savedValue) {
      return setState(JSON.parse(savedValue));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);

  return [state, setState];
}

export default useLocalStorage;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, losing saved data in localStorage with useEffect after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177643/react-losing-saved-data-in-localstorage-with-useeffect-after-page-refresh)

Comment: @yousoumar, Thanks for your suggestion but I am using Next.js, which first runs the code on the server side. And local storage is part of the browser. So I can't access local storage in the sever side first.

Comment: Hi Harshdeep, have you checked my answer below? Let me know please :)

Comment: Hi yousoumar, I have tested your given code and add some feedback about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

When your hook is rendered the first time, the callback of your first `useEffect` call `setState` by giving it the data from the storage. And the second updates the storage with `state`, which at this point is equal to the initial value given to `useState`, as the call to `setState` in the first `useEffect` takes effect after a re-render.

### Solution

You can use a `firstRender` state, and avoid updating the storage when its value is `true`. As an example like so:

```typescript
import { SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useLocalStorage(
  key: string,
  initialState: string
): [state: string, setState: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>] {
  const [state, setState] = useState<string>(initialState || "");
  const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    let savedValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (savedValue) {
      setState(JSON.parse(savedValue));
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
    }
    setFirstRender(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender) return;
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state, firstRender]);

  return [state, setState];
}

export default useLocalStorage;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the return statement in the first `useEffect` hook.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let savedValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (savedValue) {
      setState(JSON.parse(savedValue));
    }
  }, []);
```

Returning inside the `useEffect` callback is used for cleanup as stated in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup